# Unable to use variable of javascript remote method variable in chart.js code. It is coming as undefined

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting

I have to use list of accounts as labels in my chart. In order to fetch list of records I have used js remoting. I am able to fetch but not use within chart.js labels.

Here goes my vfp :-

```
    <apex:page Controller="AccountRemoter">
   <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.chartLibrary}"/>


 <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  <script>
  var names=[];
  Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
    '{!$RemoteAction.AccountRemoter.getAccountList}',        
    function(result, event) {
        var test = result;

      console.log(test);
        for (var i = 0; i< result.length ; i++){
        names.push(test[i].Name);
        }
    console.log(names[0]); // getting account
    });

   var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

  //** in this chart method I want to use names[0] and so on... **

 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
 type: 'bar',
 data: {
  labels: [names[0],names[1],names[2],names[3],names[4],names[5],names[6]],
  datasets: [{
  label: 'No. Of Contacts in each account',
  data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 20],
  backgroundColor: [
    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
  ]
  }]
   },
  options: {
  responsive: false,
  scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      maxRotation: 90,
      minRotation: 80
    }
  }],
  yAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      beginAtZero: true
    }
  }]
  }
 }
 });
```

Controller code is as follows:-

```
 global with sharing class AccountRemoter {

 @RemoteAction
    global static List<Account> getAccountList(){
      List<Account> accList=[select id,Name from account];
      return accList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Apex or Java , Javascript is non blocking language .Javascript has a concept of [callback](https://www.learn-js.org/en/Callbacks).Hence the code lines and execution need not necessarily be sequential .

Your Javascript remoting call is still under execution while the code for the charting is executed before that .

You will need to make sure that charting functions execute only after the visualforce remoting call from server returns response . Quick fix is below code which moves all script you have for chartJs inside javascript remoting callback like below .

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
'{!$RemoteAction.AccountRemoter.getAccountList}',  

function(result, event) {

    var test = result;
    var names=[];
    console.log(test);

    for (var i = 0; i< result.length ; i++){
      names.push(test[i].Name);
    }

    console.log(names[0]); // getting account

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
          labels: [names[0],names[1],names[2],names[3],names[4],names[5],names[6]],
          datasets: [{
          label: 'No. Of Contacts in each account',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 20],
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
            ]
            }]
        },
      options: {
        responsive: false,
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            maxRotation: 90,
            minRotation: 80
          }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });

});
```

If you have more than one remoting call then you will run into [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) that makes hard to maintain code. Would recommend using [Javascript Promises](https://www.salesforce.com/video/297222/) for maintainability .